# Using Objects Memory Location As Hash Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, object, hash

So I realised today in Python we can use an objects memory address location as a key in dictionary.

How does python prevent collisions in the case when the object that was at that memory location is replaced with a different one?

Are there any other risks with using the memory location as hashing key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're talking about an object's *id*, not its memory address per se. They're the same thing in CPython, but that's an implementation detail.

If so, then the docs answer your question:

> [`id(object)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)
>
> Return the "identity" of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object **during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.**
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** This is the address of the object in memory.

*(added bold)*

In other words, it *doesn't* prevent collisions.